# ScrollView's Child Not Resizing Properly With Window Resize WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

**Scenario:**
I am working on a Store App in WinRT/Win8.

I have a `ScrollView`, with a custom `UserControl` child inside - all as part of one *"main"* `UserControl`.

When the main `UserControl` (with the `ScrollView` -> child `UserControl`) in is Initialized/navigated to - even with the App width *not* full-screen; the `UserControl` is at the full width of the `ScrollView` - as desired. Images below:

- [*Image 1* - main User Control Opens with Window Fullscreen](http://gjdev.uk/img/stackoverflow/expected-full-screen-scrollview-width-on-child-desired.jpg)
- [*Image 2* - main User Control Opens Starts Half-Width (or any width)](http://gjdev.uk/img/stackoverflow/expected-half-screen-scrollview-width-on-child-navigated-to.jpg)

The `ScrollView` itself is within a `Grid` and keeps with the full width of the App window, even when it's resized - as desired.

**Issue:**
The issue I'm having is that when I resize the App window horizontally, the child `UserControl` does not keep the same width as its parent `ScrollView`'s.

This causes the `ScrollView` to then have Horizontal Scrollbars - which I do not want.

- [*Image 3* - Window Horizontal Width Resized](http://gjdev.uk/img/stackoverflow/issue-half-screen-scrollview-width-on-child-still-initial.jpg)

I want to keep the width of the child to be bound inside the width of the `ScrollView` with no Horizontal Scrollbars (as in [Image 2](http://gjdev.uk/img/stackoverflow/expected-half-screen-scrollview-width-on-child-navigated-to.jpg)).

**Markup** is similar to this (I have stripped down for readability):

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Some row/column definitions in here -->
    ...
    <!-- A header TextBlock -->
    ...
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrlTableRows" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Padding="66,0,66,40" ZoomMode="Disabled">
        <local:MyCustomUserControl Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    ...
    <!-- Just a button here-->
</Grid>
```

**I have already tried** setting (on the child custom `UserControl`):

- `Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=scrlTableRows}"`
  The child *is not* set at the full width of the `ScrollView` to start with (which is what I need), and doesn't resize the width with its parent either - giving me scrollbars
- `Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=scrlTableRows}"` The child *does* start at the full width of the parent, but doesn't resize - giving me scrollbars
- I have also tried placing the `UserControl` inside a `Grid` (within the `ScrollView`), amongst many other `HorizontalAligment` and `Width` properties.

All to no avail.

No other similar situations/answers have worked from other helpful fellows at StackOverflow.

Obviously, I need the vertical scrollbars - as is kind of evident; before anyone asks.

Can anybody give me any pointers, please?

**Update**:

Here is the custom `UserControl`'s Xaml, as requested by @LovetoCode:

```
<UserControl *usual user control declaritive stuff in here*>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="FieldViewModelsSource" Source="{Binding ItemToEdit.FieldViewModels}"/>

        <datatemplateselectors:FieldViewModelDataTemplateSelector 
            x:Key="FieldViewModelDataTemplateSelector"
            AudioFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowAudioFieldDataTemplate}"
            CheckboxFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowCheckboxFieldDataTemplate}"
            DatasetFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowDatasetFieldDataTemplate}"
            DateFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowDateFieldDataTemplate}"
            DateTimeFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowDateTimeFieldDataTemplate}"
            DropdownFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowDropdownFieldDataTemplate}"
            FileFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowFileFieldDataTemplate}"
            GpsFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowGpsFieldDataTemplate}"
            GridFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowGridFieldDataTemplate}"
            ImageFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowImageFieldDataTemplate}"
            LabelFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowLabelFieldDataTemplate}"
            MultichoiceCheckboxFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowMultichoiceCheckboxFieldDataTemplate}"
            RadioFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowRadioFieldDataTemplate}"
            RangeSliderFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowRangeSliderFieldDataTemplate}"
            SignatureFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowSignatureFieldDataTemplate}"
            SplitterFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowSplitterFieldDataTemplate}"
            TextFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowTextFieldDataTemplate}"
            TextareaFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowTextareaFieldDataTemplate}"
            TimeFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowTimeFieldDataTemplate}"
            VideoFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TableRowVideoFieldDataTemplate}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FieldViewModelsSource}}"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FieldViewModelDataTemplateSelector}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note that the `DataTemplate` resources in the `UserControl` resources are custom `UserControl`s that are loaded in based on objects in the ViewModel (like in [my original image 1](http://gjdev.uk/img/stackoverflow/expected-full-screen-scrollview-width-on-child-desired.jpg)).

Comment: Try HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"

Comment: On which control? If you're on about the custom one, I think I already have...

Comment: On  <local:MyCustomUserControl />

Comment: I said HorizontalContentAlignment not HorizontalAlignment. Please see the difference

Comment: Apologies. I read that too quickly. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have tried your suggest, but with no luck. I have tried different combinations of where the HorizontalContentAlignment was, also. Please could you post an answer with some sample code in to try?

Comment: I thought <local:MyCustomUserControl   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/> will work. You can use AdaptiveTriggers instead

Comment: Can you post your usercontrol xaml,so that i can try

Comment: I've posted the custom `UserControl` xaml, also. Thanks

Comment: Further: aren't AdaptiveTriggers only available in Win10/UWP?

Comment: Yes. I thought it's UWP. BTW did you try adding HorizontalContentAlignment to ItemsControl's items using ItemsContainerStyle?

Comment: Thought so. I'm using Win8 with WinRT. The ItemContainerStyle does not have a setter property for HorizontalContentAligment

Comment: You can use ListView instead.. Any problems?

Comment: I'm afraid that's no good - hence why I've got an `ItemsControl`

Comment: Props to you @LovetoCode! I've succeeded, after lots of swearing and denial and coffee. Your suggestion of `ListView` was indeed the one. I've posted my own answer below to reflect this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with great thanks to @LovetoCode, I managed to remedy my issue. Still trying to get over my 2-day headache and bruises from banging my head against the desk, though.

I ditched the `ScrollViewer` and just used my custom `UserControl`:

```
<local:TableRowUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Margin="66,0,66,40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Then, as @LovetoCode suggested - I used a `ListView` instead of `ItemsControl`. My most sincere apologies. I didn't want to use one first time round because...

Main issue was with the `ListView`'s default style to have hover and tap effects; which I didn't need. I tried to steer clear of disabling the hover/tap from previous experience of failing - miserably.

After a bit of Googling (other search engines are available), I found a simple solution to do this quite easily.

I managed to do it like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstFieldViewModels" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FieldViewModelsSource}}" SelectionMode="None"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FieldViewModelDataTemplateSelector}" IsSwipeEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Again, props to @LovetoCode. Gold star and programmer points for you :)